# How to store a webtable in arraylist then verify the data in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver, testng

I want to store Rows and Column of web table into array list, then will verify the data. I am available to print the rows but how I will store the rows.

```
public void verifyTable() {

String Test = driver.findElement(loggedinas).getText();


boolean isDue = false;
isDue = UtilClass.isElementPresent(driver, TableContent);

if (isDue) {
    if (isDue = driver.findElement(TableContent).getText() != null)
        ;
    System.out.println("Action Required = " + isDue);

    WebElement table_element = driver.findElement(Table);
    List<WebElement> tr_collection = table_element
            .findElements(TableRow);
    System.out.println("Number Of Due = " + tr_collection.size());

    int row_num, col_num;

    row_num = 1;
    for (WebElement trElement : tr_collection) {
        List<WebElement> td_collection = trElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));

        System.out.println("--NUMBER OF COLUMNS = "
                + td_collection.size() + "--");

        col_num = 1;
        for (WebElement tdElement : td_collection) {
            // System.out.println("Pending # "+row_num+", col # "+col_num+
            // "text="+tdElement.getText());

            System.out.printf(" # " + tdElement.getText(), " ID "
                    + tdElement.getText());
            col_num++;

        }
        row_num++;

    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try using a 2-dimensional ArrayList?

Comment: Thanks @ApurvChatterjee working fine, just curious if table have duplicate EmpID  but have diff. Emp names ,then how to use value.contains("EmpID")

Comment: Hi @sumit I believe we can have a separate thread for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had done something similar, please check this function bellow, this will give you an idea

```
public void manageUserDataGrid(WebDriver driver){
    WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ReportTable']"));
    List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    List<WebElement> column = table.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    List<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();

    System.out.println(rows.size());

        for (int j=0; j<column.size(); j++){
            System.out.println(column.get(j).getText());
            value.add(column.get(j).getText());
        }
        if (value.contains("coadminss")){
            System.out.println("Value found");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Not Found");
        }
}
```